# How do i start Mintty and run a script file?

Tags: curl, cmd, mintty

I wrote a simple CURL and put it in a script file.

if i run mintty first and then "test.sh" it runs the script in the file just fine.  Works perfectly.

however, if i try to run mintty with any of the following command line, it will not run.  I'm running these in CMD

```
C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/test.sh'

C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec '/bin/test.sh'

C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec '/test.sh'

C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec 'test.sh'

C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec 'c:/test.sh'

C:\>c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe --exec 'c:\test.sh'
```

Comment: C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash -l
the line above works fine, but with "-e '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/test.sh'" the consolewindow opens for 1 sec, then it will close.

Answer (score 11):

For whoever is interested in this... here is the solution

Create a shortcut in windows for `mintty` with the following target

Assuming your shell file is located in c:\cygwin\bin

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash -l -e '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/test.sh'
```

Comment: I found my `mintty.exe` and `bash.exe`  in `C:\cygwin64\bin\`

Answer (score 2):

Try running bash.exe directly (or some other shell that installed with cygwin).

From a windows shell, change directory to your cygwin install and run this:

```
C:\cygwin\bin>bash.exe /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/test.sh
```

To get the shell script to run by double clicking a shortcut

1) Put the command in a .bat file

```
test.bat
---------------------------------------------------------------------
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/test.sh

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2) Create a shortcut using test.bat as the target.

I tried making a shortcut with bash.exe and the command as a target.  That errors out for some reason. However, wrapping the command in a .bat file works.  Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

I also use the solution offered by nkman, but I add the '-h always' option so that the console remains opened until I hit enter, to see what happened. So this is the target of my shortcut:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -h always /bin/bash -l -e '/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Administrator/startup.sh'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Best solution in my opinion:

Invokes the right shell, no unnecessary windows and invokes a bash script afterwards which will be hold.

- **Create a Shortcut** to `mintty.exe` on your desktop, for example
- **Edit properties** of the shortcut and change the target (keep the path):
- `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -h always /bin/bash -l -e 'D:\folder\script.sh'`